# How does NumPy implement its complex number literal?

Tags: python, numpy

Using complex number in Numpy is as simple as np.exp(1+ 2.3j). How to implement this simple notation? What is 2.3j? It's not like that it is a variable name.

Comment: Using `j` as a literal for the imaginary unit is part of Python's syntax; it's not really a NumPy thing.

Comment: A complex value is stored as 2 floats, as shown by `np.array([1, 2.3],float).view(complex)` which returns `array([ 1.+2.3j])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex numbers [are a built-in data type in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

You can do complex number operations right inside the interpreter without `numpy` if you like:

```
>> (2+3j) * (-1j)
(3-2j)
```

Comment: Thank you... it's so embarrassing.

Comment: @jvchn It's a somewhat surprising feature if you are new to Python. Unlike many other languages, you don't need to include a library to start using them, you can write the natural syntax `2+3j` rather than something like `complex(2,3)`.